# Connection to Database installed on Unix server

Tags: oracle, ssms

I am getting below error when trying to connect to database which is installed on UNIX server through SQL management.

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

I can successfully connect it through Oracle SQL developer.

I know this question has already been asked a number of times , I have gone through all those

one of the resolution i got is utility to add the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\
```

But I want to know how can I make it work if in case where host is UNIX server.

[image]

Comment: If you can connect through SQL developer, it means the server doesn't have any problem (Unix or not don't matter). The problem would be with your calling code then. How did you connect to database server?

Comment: I am giving these inputs(can be seen in above screenshot ) in SQL management studio to make a connection to ORACLE Database installed on unix server.

Comment: You can't use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to Oracle directly. You need to setup a linked server as per https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e6d61861-b271-4d93-b14e-12ba9356798f/connect-to-oracle-via-sql-server-management-studio?forum=sqltools.

Comment: agree, 

i googled for this kind of error and found out that these exceptions are generally thrown by data providers...

Can this problem be resolved by installing SQL native client on Host server ?